# How can I concatenate an IP address? Run time error 13 , Type mismatch

Tags: vba, outlook, network-programming

I know I have a problem with

```
IPROUTER = (Left(IP, 11)) & ((Right(IP, 3)) + 5)
```

How should I write this line to not get titled error?

```
Dim ID As String
Dim IP As String
Dim IPROUTER As String
 
ID = Mid(olItem.Subject, 20, 9)
IP = Right(olItem.Body, 14)
  
IPROUTER = (Left(IP, 11)) & ((Right(IP, 3)) + 5)
  
With objFile
    .WriteLine "START " & Chr(34) & ID & Chr(34) & " ping" & IP & " -t"
```

Comment: Where are you executing this code from? Excel? Can you be more specific about your problem? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I execute this code in Outlook. I want to create bat script to ping machines from data from mails.

Comment: Ok, Can you print a screen of the error you get?

Comment: Run time error 13 , Type mismatch , when i debug i see that the problem is with line: IPROUTER = (Left(IP, 11)) & ((Right(IP, 3)) + 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. It didn't help but I figured it out in a diffrent way. I just convert string to int. Code of my example below:

```
Dim ID As String
Dim IP As String
Dim IPROUTER As String
Dim ok As String
Dim okI As Integer


ID = Mid(olItem.Subject, 20, 9)
IP = Right(olItem.Body, 14)



 IPROUTER = (Left(IP, 12))

 ok = Mid(IP, 13, 3)
 okI = CInt(ok)





 With objFile
  .WriteLine "START " & Chr(34) & ID & Chr(34) & " ping " & IP & " -t"
  .WriteLine "START " & Chr(34) & ID & Chr(34) & " ping " & IPROUTER & okI + 5 & " -t"
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `Type mismatch` error because with your code, you're trying to add an `Integer` to a `String` (because you have a `.` in your `String`).

Assuming that your IP address is a **class C** type (like `192.168.1.x`), you can correct your code like this:

```
IPROUTER = (Left(IP, 10)) & (Mid(IP, 11, 3) + 5)
```

This will work whatever is the size of the last octect, but you may have to change somenthing based on the lenght of your address fixed part.

Hope this helps.